# Comments in Salesforce contact email address

Tags: email, contact

According to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321158&type=1&language=en_US&mode=1, Salesforce supports comments in email addresses

> Comments - denoted by matched parentheses - are allowed in the domain
> as well as in the local-part. Comments in an email address are ignored
> when sending email; for example, john.doe@(comment)example.com, and
> john.doe@example.com(comment) are both equivalent to
> john.doe@example.com.

This does not seem to be the case as this procedure can be seen failing with the error "You have entered an invalid format." on the following screenshot(here I am assigning this email address to a Contact):

[image: Error message]

This example was copy-pasted straight from the Salesforce help article, so it should be sufficient to demonstrate the inoperability of this functionality. I also tested placing comments before the @ and after the @ and before the domain name -- all options failed.

I understand that this functionality is quite niche and largely more weird and unintuitive than helpful, however I believe it would help me solve an on-going production issue, so I'm a bit baffled as to how this RFC approved format seems to not be accepted in this field.

Comment: From RFC 2822: _Some legacy implementations used the simple form where the addr-spec appears without the angle brackets, but included the name of the recipient in parentheses as a comment following the addr-spec. Since the meaning of the information in a comment is unspecified, implementations SHOULD use the full name-addr form of the mailbox, instead of the legacy form, to specify the display name associated with a mailbox.  Also, because some legacy implementations interpret the comment, comments generally SHOULD NOT be used in address fields to avoid confusing such implementations_

Comment: Regardless of what the RFC says, SF might accept the legacy format of address or non-legacy format with angle brackets or none of the above.